# Visual Studio 2013 References missing due to nuget

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reference, nuget, nuget-package-restore

i started VS 2013 today and all references were missing, the config files looked ok but in VS there were no PATHs set.

I tried to restore this with the pkgmanager nuget, still no PATH entries of the dll's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on [this blog](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html) by following the instructions found [here](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore) with Example files.

1. Close down Visual Studio
2. With TFS:

   - Remove the NuGet.exe and NuGet.targets files from the solution's .nuget folder. Make sure the files themselves are also removed from the solution workspace.
   - Retain the NuGet.Config file to continue to bypass adding packages to source control.
   - Edit each project file (e.g., .csproj, .vbproj) in the solution and remove any references to the NuGet.targets file
3. Without TFS:

   - Remove the .nuget folder from your solution. Make sure the folder itself is also removed from the solution workspace.
   - Edit each project file (e.g., .csproj, .vbproj) in the solution and remove any references to the NuGet.targets file.

Comment: Link only answers are [not considered good answers on StackOverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please edit your answer to list the steps you took as well as providing the links.